# How to use $_ in content without been replaced by powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to replace a word to some php code

```
$filecontent = [regex]::Replace($filecontent, $myword, $phpcode)
```

But the $phpcode have some php code using also a Special variable $_

```
<?php $cur_author = (isset($_GET['author_name'])) ? get_user_by('slug', $author_name) : get_userdata(intval($author)); ?>
```

The problem is when the code is replace in $filecontent it replaces the $_ variable from the php code ( $_GET ) with it have on the pipeline.

This not happen with the other variables like $author_name .

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
$filecontent = [regex]::Replace($filecontent, $myword, {$phpcode})
```

In a regex replace operation the $_ is a reserved substituion pattern that represents the entire string

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx

Wrapping it in braces makes it a scriptblock delegate, bypassing the normal regex pattern matching algorithms for doing the replacement.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options.  First use a single quoted string and PowerShell will treat that as a verbatim string (C# term) i.e. it won't try to string interpolate:

```
'$_ is passed through without interpretation'
```

The other option is to escape the `$` character in a double quoted string:

```
"`$_ is passed through without interpretation"
```

When I'm messing with a regex I will default to using single quoted strings unless I have a variable that needs to be interpolated inside the string.

Another possibility is that `$_` is being interpreted by regex as a substitution group in which case you need to use the substitution escape on the `$` e.g. `$$`.

Comment: I don't think Powershell interpretation is the problem in this case.  It's that $_ is a reserved term for a substitution pattern (entire string) in regex.

Comment: Well it depends on how the string in $phpcode is being constructed. If the OP is using a double-quoted string then PowerShell interpolates *before* the regex sees the string. But from the question it is kind of hard to tell exactly what is going on.  Can't see the contents of $myword.  And the OP says it replaces the $_ with "the pipeline".  :-(

Comment: He says the other patterns that could be interpreted as powershell variables aren't a problem, only the $_.  I inferrred from that the string is being single quoted.

Comment: I tried escaping the substition pattern, and it didn't work.  It just added a \ to the substituted string.

Comment: Sorry for the replacement side, you substitute with `$$`. I updated my answer to reflect that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Cool.  I didn't know what the escape was for that.  Switching to a scriptblock delegate worked, and seemed like a simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure I am following you correctly, but does this help?

```
$file = path to your file
$oldword = the word you want to replace
$newword = the word you want to replace it with
```

If the Oldword you are replacing has special charactes ( ie.  \ or $ ) then you must escape them first.  You can escape them by putting a backslash in front of the special character.  The Newword, does not need to be escaped.  A $ would become "\$".

```
(get-content $file) | foreach-object {$_ -replace $oldword,$NewWord} | Set-Content $file
```